# Auth0 not working w/Authentication Social and a Whitelist rule

Tags: auth0, auth0-connection

I have an app using auth0. I have it setup to just use google-oauth2 for authentication. I then went into Rules from dashboard and created a rule to whitelist several emails. However in testing this out the whitelist is not working. Anyone w/a legitimate gmail account is able to get in. Have I missed something? Any suggestions most welcome.

Comment: +1, I'm in a similar boat. The whitelisted emails are able to log in only via google-oauth2. username & password log-in are not working for whitelisted emails.

Comment: Be careful w/case sensitivity. I found my problem was that.